# Probability of taking an odd number of throws to get 6

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, dice

Throw a dice until get 6.What's the probability that total number of throw is odd?

My approach:
throw 1 time : $1/6$

throw 3 times : $(5/6)^2*1/6$

throw 5 times : $(5/6)^4 * 1/6$

...and sum them up.It is a geometric sequence with first term $a_1 = 1/6$ and ratio = $ 25/36$

So the answer is $(1/6)/(1-25/36) = 6/11$

Am I on the correct path? My friend says I should use conditional probability,but I don't quite get it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780394/probability-of-rolling-the-first-6-on-an-even-throw) is a duplicate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your method, and the duplicate will show you some alternative arguments for the result.

Comment: Thanks for providing another inspiring method!